# Prove that minimal polynomial of $T =$ minimal polynomial of$ A$, if$ T(B) = AB$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_{2×2}(F) $and deﬁne $T(B) = AB$ for $B \in M_{2×2}(F)$.
(i)Prove that $cT(x) = (cA(x))^2$.
  (ii) Prove that $mT(x) = mA(x)$.
  (iii) Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

I managed to prove (i) 
For(ii), I know that since $mA(x)$ divides $cA(x)$, it must also divide $[cA(x)]^2 = cT(x)$ and equals to zero as they share the same eigenvalues. However, I am not sure how to write the proof out? Can someone help?

For(iii), I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the steps to prove the desired result:

We have

- $T^2(B)=T(T(B))=T(AB)=A\cdot (AB)=A^2B$ and similarly by induction $$T^k(B)=A^k B$$
- we get so that if $P$ is a polynomial then

$$P(T)(B)=P(A)B$$

- hence if $m_T$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ then we get

$$m_T(A)B=0\;\forall B\implies m_T(A)=0$$
hence the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$ divides $m_T$. The converse is easy and we get
$$m_T=m_A=:m$$

- $T$ is diagonalizable iff $m_T$ splits into linear factor with simple roots iff $m_A$ splits into linear factor with simple roots iff $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: To prove the converse, can I use:
$$m_A(T)(B)=0\;\forall B\implies m_A(T)=0$$
hence the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $A$ divides $m_A$?  
Side Question: Is there any way I can use the result from part(ii) to answer part(iii)?

Comment: Yes this is the converse.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to reply me!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For part(iii),

$T$ is diagonalizable iff it's minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors.

Since Minimal polynomial of $T = $ Minimal polynomial of $A, A$ is also diagonalizable as it's 
minimal polynomial is also a product of distinct linear factors.